# Multiple tables and queries

Tags: php, mysql

How do I join something like this together:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM profiles,follow
           WHERE follow.friend ='$user' 
               AND follow.user !='$user' 
               AND profiles.user1 =follow.user 
           ORDER BY id DESC limit 20");
```

or

```
("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user1='$user'");
```

I need the query to display two different things how do I do that.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but are you trying to fetch 20 rows from the first query + all the rows from the second in one query?

Comment: Your question does not seem to make sense. Why do you at first want to fetch 20 rows from profiles and follow and then after that select a single user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION:

```
SELECT * 
FROM profiles, follow
WHERE follow.friend ='$user' 
  AND follow.user !='$user' 
  AND profiles.user1 =follow.user 
  ORDER BY id DESC limit 20
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM profiles 
WHERE user1='$user'
```

Answer (score 1):

This one?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    follows
INNER JOIN
    profiles
    ON (profiles.user1 = follow.user)
WHERE
    follow.friend = '{$user}'
    AND follow.user != '{$user}'
    AND profiles.user1 = '{$user}'
ORDER BY
    profiles.id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I rephrased the question can you answer it again sorry.

Comment: i solved he problem i saved the data that i need in a array then used it later it seemed to solve the problem thanks.

Comment: np, but I just don't understand what is the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profiles,follow WHERE follow.friend ='$user' and follow.user !='$user' and profiles.user1 =follow.user and profiles.user1='$user' order by id DESC limit 20";
```